# Не работает команда vagrant box add laravel/homestead (Windows 10)

Tags: laravel, vagrant

Хочу установить Laravel под Windows 10.
Установил Vagrant версии 2.2.19

Выполнил git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git и init.bat
Из каталога, куда установился homestead, запускаю команду

vagrant box add laravel/homestead

В ответ получаю следующее

> The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or could not be
> accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on
> HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via `vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error
> message are shown below:
>
> URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead"] Error: The
> requested URL returned error: 404

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Если перейти по ссылки, то: This content is not currently available in your region.

Comment: С VPN с американским IP то же самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой.

Vagrant в рамках санкций заблокировал российские IP адреса (а так же те иностранные IP адреса, которые принадлежат российским хостерам).
Надо использовать VPN, у которого администратором IP-адресов указана иностранная компания. Использование прокси вместо VPN не поможет, vagrant с ними работать не будет без установки дополнительного модуля vagrant-proxyconf.

Можно скачать виртуальную машину Homestead или отдельным файлом со страницы
https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

и после этого выполнить команду

vagrant box add laravel/homestead "путь до скачанного файла"
(если в пути присутствуют пробелы, то кавычки обязательны)

или сразу выполнить команду

vagrant box add laravel/homestead

и она вначале скачает файл с виртуальной машиной, а потом добавит её в Virtualbox

После этого, чтобы запустить виртуальную машину, надо выполнить

vagrant up

Предварительно надо прописать все настройки и пути до ваших проектов в Homestead.yaml